# Is there any polling on the Democratic primaries that includes Bloomberg?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, democratic-primary, michael-bloomberg

Michael Bloomberg has [announced](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-50539242) yesterday that he officially joins the Democratic primaries race. This seems a bit late in the game, so to speak, but maybe he knows something we don't. So, is there any (publically available) polling on the Democratic primaries that includes his candidacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we *do*, going by [Five Thirty Eight's *We’ve Got Some New Polls For Bloomberg’s Potential Campaign. They Aren’t Great.*](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/weve-got-some-new-polls-for-bloombergs-potential-campaign-they-arent-great/) dated 15 November 2019 (links from the article, emphasis on numbers mine, I split the paragraph to distinguis between polls):

> Shortly after news broke that Bloomberg might run, Morning Consult ran a [quick poll](https://morningconsult.com/2019/11/10/bloomberg-is-top-choice-for-4-percent-of-democratic-primary-voters/) that found he would pull **4 percent of the national primary vote**. That’s [about where he was polling](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-seriously-should-we-take-michael-bloombergs-potential-2020-run/) before he initially said he [wouldn’t run](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/05/us/politics/michael-bloomberg-2020.html), back in March: not terrible, but hardly strong enough to pose a serious threat. And even though Bloomberg’s advisers have said he would actually [skip the first four primary states](https://apnews.com/653386c5e7e040d09836d0e013558815) if he runs — a truly unorthodox strategy — two early-state polls that also asked about him this week found that he barely registered there.
>
> Only **2 percent of likely Democratic primary voters in New Hampshire** [told Quinnipiac](https://poll.qu.edu/new-hampshire/release-detail?ReleaseID=3648) that they would “definitely vote” for Bloomberg, although an **additional 37 percent did say they would “consider voting” for him**.
>
> And in a [Monmouth poll](https://www.monmouth.edu/polling-institute/documents/monmouthpoll_ia_111219.pdf/) of **Iowa**, Bloomberg earned the support of less than **1 percent of likely Democratic caucusgoers**.
>
> And it might be especially hard for Bloomberg to increase his support considering his lackluster favorability numbers. In that Morning Consult poll, his **favorable rating was 31 percent** and his **unfavorable rating was 25 percent**.

> A YouGov/Economist poll this week gave him a **34 percent favorable rating and a 36 percent unfavorable rating among Democratic primary voters nationwide**.
>
> And that Monmouth poll found that just **17 percent of Iowa Democrats viewed him favorably, while 48 percent viewed him unfavorably**!